# Calling a function in another function causing error due to arguments in parantheses

Tags: python, function

As it happens I am just getting into programming with Python and I was about to program a little rock-paper-scissors game.

Unfortunately when I'm trying to run my script, I am receiving the following error:

```
file rps.py, line 53 in game    
   compare (move,choice)     
  NameError: name 'move' is not defined"
```

Here's my code so far:

```
from random import randint
possibilities = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']

def CPU(list):
    i =  randint(0, len(list)-1)
    move = list[i]
    #print (str(move))
    return move

def User():
    choice = str(input('Your choice? (Rock [r], Paper[p], Scissors[s])'))
    choice = choice.lower()

    if choice == 'rock' or choice == 'r':
        choice = 'rock'
    elif choice == 'scissors' or choice =='s':
        choice = 'scissors'
    elif choice == 'paper' or choice == 'p':
        choice = 'paper'

    #print ('Your choice: ' + str(choice))
    return choice


def compare(c, u):
    if c == u:
         print ('Your choice was: ' + str(u) + 'and I chose: ' + str(c))
         print ('That is what we call a tie. Nobody wins.')
    elif c == 'paper' and u == 'rock':
         print ('Your choice was: ' + str(u) + 'and I chose: ' + str(c))
         print ('This means that you, my friend, lose.')
    elif c == 'paper' and u == 'scissors':
         print ('Your choice was: ' + str(u) + 'and I chose: ' + str(c))
         print ('Congratulations, you win....this time.')
    elif cc == 'rock' and u == 'paper':
         print ('Your choice was: ' + str(u) + 'and I chose: ' + str(c))
         print ('Congratulations, you win....this time.')
    elif c == 'rock' and u == 'scissors':
         print ('Your choice was: ' + str(u) + 'and I chose: ' + str(c))
         print ('This means that you lose.')
    elif c == 'scissors' and u == 'paper':
         print ('Your choice was: ' + str(u) + 'and I chose: ' + str(c))
         print ('This means that you lose.')
    elif c == 'scissors' and u == 'rock':
         print ('Your choice was: ' + str(u) + 'and I chose: ' + str(c))
         print ('Congratulations, you win....this time.')

def game():
    CPU(possibilities)
    User()
    compare(move, choice)

game()
```

I am pretty sure that I did something wrong when I defined the function `compare(c,u)` and added the arguments 'c' and 'u' in the parentheses.
I thought that I made sure that I was able to use these variables  by using the return statement before.

I am quite new to programming in general and therefore inexperienced, so please be kind!

Comment: Nothing to do with parenthesis. Read the error: it says there is no name `move` (variable, function) in scope. That is all. Also, please make sure to post *valid* (formatted) code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are only calling the functions `CPU` and `User` but you are not assigning them to any variables. Hence you need to re-define your function `game` as in

```
def game():
    move = CPU(possibilities)
    choice = User()
    compare(move, choice)
```

In this way you will be calling the function `compare` with a local copy of the values `return`ed after calling the two other functions.

You can refer more about functions and the `return` statement by referring the official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)